# Get Maps autocomplete as input Value

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps autocomplete API to help select places for input field. The issue is, if I try to get the input value to use in something such as Firebase or similar it only saves what I typed prior to selecting autocomplete. Please see this CodePen: https://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/KWRjNp?editors=1111 I've been using the below `console.log` to try to reflect the autocomplete value.

The usage is pretty basic so I'm surprised I haven't seen more of this issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Address</label>
        <input v-model="newPost.address" type="text" class="form-control" id="searchTextField" placeholder="Address">
    </div>
    <div class="place"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInput);

searchInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        let addr = searchInput.value;
        let embed = "<label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Map Preview</label><iframe frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q=" + encodeURIComponent(addr) + "&amp;output=embed'></iframe>";

        $('.place').html(embed);
    }, 200);
    console.log(searchInput.value)

});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a little bit tricky because `place` is an object and the autocomplete results you are seeing are derived from the properties of Place object.

So the workaround I did to get to what you're trying to do is combine two place properties - `place.name` and `place.formatted_address`. You can find the [full list here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#GeocoderAddressComponent).

Here's the [full demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7sdxs4vb/18/) which I tweaked from [Place Autocomplete sample from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
var inputValue = place.name + " " + place.formatted_address;
console.log(inputValue);
```

**Sample Autcomplete Demo**

**Looking for:** Sydney Opera House

**Autocomplete result:**
Wilson Parking - Sydney Opera House, Macquarie Street, Sydney, New South Wales, Australia

**place input value obtained:** 
Wilson Parking - Sydney Opera House 2 Macquarie St, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia

**Looking for**: Statue of Liberty

**Autocomplete result:**
Statue of Liberty Departure, New York, NY, United States

**place input value obtained:** 
Statue of Liberty Departure New York, NY 10004, USA

You can see the results are almost exactly the same. You can now use the variable `inputValue` (which is an almost identical copy of the autocomplete result) however you want. 
Hope this helps.